# Controlling Multiple Text Boxes with same event Type

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have a C# WPF Window in which I have 20 textboxes.  They don't do anything special, and all i want is when I went them for the text to be selected.

I know it's fairly each to set up 20 events like

```
private void customerTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    customerTextBox.SelectAll();
}
```

but i'm wondering if theres something smoother like

```
private void (genericTextBox)_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (genericTextBox).SelectAll();
}
```

where I can just use this once and each textbox understands to user that event

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sender` argument which contains the reference to the textbox that raised the event:

```
private void GenericTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TextBox).SelectAll();
}
```

You can then set this error handler for all your textboxes:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox1" GotFocus="GenericTextBox_GotFocus" />
<TextBox x:Name="textBox2" GotFocus="GenericTextBox_GotFocus" />
<TextBox x:Name="textBox3" GotFocus="GenericTextBox_GotFocus" />
<TextBox x:Name="textBox4" GotFocus="GenericTextBox_GotFocus" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "sender" parameter to write one handler for multiple TextBoxes.
Example:

```
private void textBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    if (sender == null)
    {
       return;
    }
    textBox.SelectAll();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your event handler as you did in your example and then point all your textbox's GotFocus event to that handler.

Answer (score 0):

you can use RegisterClassHandler method like this:

```
 EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(YourClass), TextBox.GotFocusEvent, new RoutedEventHandler((s, e) =>
        {(s as TextBox).SelectAll();};
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to creating the generic handler as aforementioned, you can also add a line of code to your window's constructor so you do not have to attach the handler in xaml to each textbox.

```
this.AddHandler(TextBox.GotFocusEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(TextBox_GotFocus));
```