# Create class to check if textbox is empty etc

Tags: c#, class, textbox

I need help on how to make and use a class that checks multiple things in multiple textbox's.

Now my problem is that I have around 50 textbox's and I've added the code that I need to every single one of them.
I've showed someone my code and he told me I can create a class, for example "Validation", and just add a method for every single validation that I need and simply use class.methodname instead of multiple lines of code for every single textbox

Now my questions are:
- how do I create such a class from scratch?
- how do I actually use this class in my code?
- how do I add a method to check if a textbox is not empty?
- how do I add a method to check if a textbox only contains letters/numbers and spaces, even when the text gets pasted into the textbox?
- how do I add a method to check if a folder already exists?

Codes that I've currently added to every textbox that needs these validations are the following:

Check if textbox is empty or not

```
if (txtName.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a name!", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Check if textbox contains alphanumeric characters, doesn't work for pasted text though

```
private void txtName_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
 if ((e.Key < Key.A) || (e.Key > Key.Z))
    e.Handled = true;
 }
```

And lastly check if a folder already exists

```
string folderName = "";
bool exists= false;

folderName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), txtName.text);
    exists= System.IO.Directory.Exists(folderName);

    if (exists)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This name is already in use", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    else
    { 
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);                    
    }
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Sounds like a **great** fit for [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Do you need same validations for every textbox like **is it empty** or **contains letters/numbers and spaces** etc ?

Comment: @Tim I've come across that, unless I'm mistaking you cannot use this for multiple forms right? Unless you copy paste the extension methods you need in every form?

Comment: @Steven - put the extension methods in a separate class and assembly, and reference that assembly in your project and include it in a `using` directive on the pages that need it.  Or even just a separate class in your project - if it's in the same namespace you won't need a `using` directive.

Comment: @Shaharyar I need to check if its empty, if it is give error, if its not check if it contains only number/letters/spaces if it doesn't give error if it it does proceed. But I need to do this for multiple boxes on multiple forms

Comment: You can use same event handler for multiple textboxes which should act same for specific kind of event or condition. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074920/controlling-multiple-text-boxes-with-same-event-type

Comment: @Tim To be sure I understand correctly, I have to create a new class in my project, for example "Validation", in this class I add for example a method called "Empty" with the code to check if a textbox is empty or not. Then in my form I use Validation.Empty(textbox.text);. Is this about right?

Comment: @Steven - pretty much.  The class and methods must be `static` and use `this` as the first argument in the methods.  You can have as many methods as you want/need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of Class `MyTextBox` Inherited From `TextBox` and Use `this` to refer CurrentTextBox

Use this `MyTextBox` in Your Code where ever you want

```
class MyTextBox : TextBox
    {

        public bool IsMyTextBoxEmpty()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Text.Trim()))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public bool IsContainsValideSpaces()
        {
           //...........Your Logic is Here
            return false;
        }


        public bool IsCopied()
        {
            //...........Your Logic is Here
            return false;
        }
    }
```